# Visual Basic Hangman Random Function

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck with the random function cause I'm not sure how to apply it on my code

The below code is in the PlayButton.. Button

```
Dim number As Integer
number = Int(Rnd() * ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) + 1
Word = ListBox1.Items(number)'Word is a string and it holds the word to be guessed
```

This is what I wrote... 
This way it works fine, but when the game starts, it starts with the same word over and over... Specifically RUN :P

and even though it continues with random words those random words are sometimes repeated 2 or even 3 times (mostly 2) ...

(Also I have 10 words inside the listbox, Run is one of them)

Well, I don't want it to start every time with the word RUN :L

Comment: Use the shiny new NET `Random` class in place of the legacy VB `Rnd` function...or use `Randomize` before you pick

Comment: Meaning? xD sry if I sound so noob :P

Comment: Click on any of the links under **Related** on the right.  Surely you dont think this is a new and unique question?

Comment: No but I searched it specifically for hangman :P but maybe I missed some details ... sry if it's not unique... I searched Stack Overflow many times... I'll double check again

Comment: Hangman has nothing to do with it.  Your question relates to picking a random number...how it is used is irrelevant

Comment: When your cursor is on Rnd(), try pressing F1. The first overload already explain what you need (the Randomize() call). Microsoft work so hard to put relevant explanation for each of their humongous API, use it.

Comment: Ok.. I'll try thx anyways :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information the Random class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx).

As a quick usage tip, you will likely want to have a class level attribute defined at class initiation:

```
Private _rand As New Random()
```

And then when you are retrieving the next random value you would do something like:

```
number = _rand.Next(ListBox1.Items.Count)
```

That will return a number in the range of 0 to (ListBox1.Items.Count -1)

Comment: Every time you start vb.net, the seed number for generating the next random number (using the rnd function) is always the same.  Using code in the answer from @NathanC, vb.net sets the seed number based on the current system time when _rand is declared.  I should point out that the initial declaration of _rand should be done only once at the beginning of your program. If you keep declaring it near where you are using it, and use it several times in less than a second, you will get the same random number multiple times.

Comment: WOW.. DAMN.. I'M SUCH A NOOB... I knew this already.. but, I forgot it really easy cause.. well right now I'm learning a lot of languages and after I finish college I would like to just be on ONE language so I won't mess my mind with 100(exaggeration ofc :P) Languages that exist... So thank you very much.. that was EXACTLY the answer to my question xD :D... Can't thank you enough :D

Comment: No problem. Good luck with it